# Python Flask "werkzeug.routing.BuildError" after renaming html file in templates folder

Tags: python, flask

my flask server is behaving really weirdly i had a route like this

```py
@app.route('/login' , methods=['GET' , 'POST'])
def register():
    return render_template('login.html')
```

this worked perfectly and gave me the page when i requested it
but then i renamed the file name to "register.html"

```py
@app.route('/register' , methods=['GET' , 'POST'])
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

and now this gives  me error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/register'. Did you mean 'register' instead?

Now i tried to change the route path with different names multiple times:

```py
@app.route('/anypathname' , methods=['GET' , 'POST'])
def register():
    return render_template('register.html')
```

it STILL gives me error: werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/register'. Did you mean 'register' instead?

shouldn't this error say "werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/anypathname'. Did you mean 'anypathname' instead?"

i tried to restart server clear browser cache and  the flask auto reloads on code change too its debugger is working. but it still gives me this error

Comment: Could it be that you used `url_for` and passed the path instead of the endpoint?

Comment: @Detlef i did write this when my file name was "login.html" in the route function: `return redirect(url_for('home'))`

Comment: There is no bug in this code. The error may not be thrown in the route but in the template. Sorry, I only know this error from incorrect parameters when using `url_for` or duplicate names for endpoints. Can the error message indicate in which area the error is thrown?

Comment: @Detlef i made a new html file called "registerAccount.html" copied the code from "register.html" and put it in the renderTemplate parameter but it still didn't work.

Comment: i can't understand the error logs

Comment: Please add the error logs to the question. Otherwise I could only imagine that the indication of the 'action' parameter in your form could be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple example of user registration. The code is a little reduced due to the length. Maybe it will help you a little.

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, PasswordField

from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Length, EqualTo, Regexp, Email
from wtforms.validators import ValidationError

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField(
        'Username',
        validators=[
            InputRequired(),
            Length(3,20),
            Regexp(
                '^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_\.]*$',
                message='Username must have only letters, numbers, dots or underscores.')
        ],

    )
    email = StringField(
        'E-Mail',
        validators=[
            InputRequired(),
            Email()
        ],
    )
    password = PasswordField(
        'Password',
        validators=[
            InputRequired(),
            EqualTo('password_confirm',
                message='Password confirmation invalid.')
        ],
    )
    password_confirm = PasswordField(
        'Password Confirmation',
        validators=[
            InputRequired(),  
        ],
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Register')

    def validate_email(self, field):
        if User.query.filter_by(email=field.data).first():
            raise ValidationError('Email already registered.')

    def validate_username(self, field):
        if User.query.filter(User.username.ilike(field.data)).first():
            raise ValidationError('Username already in use.')
```

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User()
            form.populate_obj(user)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        else:
            flash("Your user has been created, please login.", category="success")
            return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

# ... (login, etc.)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Flask App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.email.label() }}
      {{ form.email(class='form-control') }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.username.label() }}
      {{ form.username(class='form-control') }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.password.label() }}
      {{ form.password(class='form-control') }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.password_confirm.label() }}
      {{ form.password_confirm(class='form-control') }}
      </div>
      {{ form.submit(class='btn btn-primary btn-block') }}
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was pointing to "/register" in a "a" tag link in "register.html" but it should be "register" not "/register"

````html
 <a href="{{ url_for('register') }}"><button class="login-btn">Register</button></a>

not:

 <a href="{{ url_for('/register') }}"><button class="login-btn">Register</button></a>
```html
````